# laravel razor payment api

Tags: laravel, api, razorpay

I am trying to implement razor payment api in laravel project, facing lot of issues

```
include(app_path().'/includes/razor/Razorpay.php');
use Razorpay\Api\Api;

class OwnerController extends BaseController 
{
    if (Config::get('app.default_payment') == 'razor') {
        $api_key = "rzp_test_f***wPfD7sR29W";
        $api_secret = "lJ********u81oURV8CEA3Yf";
        $api = new Api($api_key, $api_secret);
        $customer = $api->customer->create(array(
            'name' => 'Razorpay User6', 
            'email' => 'customer6@razorpay.com'
        )); // Creates customer
        print_r($customer);
        die();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Requests class found but did not match

Please help me with this

I have put razor folder inside `app/includes/razor`

Comment: literally you included library like this `include(app_path().'/includes/razor/Razorpay.php');
`

Comment: ya. is it wrong. i am new to laravel

Comment: create a folder in your app folder place this lib there and use it using namespaces

Comment: And I hope the API and secret you've posted are not the real values.

Answer (score 0):

1. add package using this command "composer require razorpay/razorpay"
2. After add this line in top of controller "use Razorpay\Api\Api;"
3. update composer "composer update"